# RSA encryption stopped working when server was joined to domain

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I had a working RSA encryption that was basically created like this

```
public string DecryptFormula( byte[] WholeData )
{
    // Get from container the key used to encrypt entropy bytes 
    RSAParameters PublicKey = GetKeyFromContainer("CorroredKeys");

    byte[] KeyLengthByte = new byte[4];
    Array.Copy(WholeData, KeyLengthByte, 4);
    int KeyLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(KeyLengthByte, 0);
    // Encrypt entropy
    byte[] encryptedKey = new byte[KeyLength];
    Array.Copy(WholeData, 4, encryptedKey, 0, KeyLength);

    //Pass the data to ENCRYPT, the public key information  
    //(using RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(false), 
    //and a boolean flag specifying no OAEP padding.
    byte[] PrivateKey = RSADecrypt(encryptedKey, PublicKey, false);
    ...
}
    static public byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] DataToDecrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] decryptedData;
            //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider. 
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                //Import the RSA Key information. This needs 
                //to include the private key information.
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

                //Decrypt the passed byte array and specify OAEP padding.   
                //OAEP padding is only available on Microsoft Windows XP or 
                //later.  
                decryptedData = RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
            }
            return decryptedData;
        }
        //Catch and display a CryptographicException   
        //to the console. 
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {             
            return null;
        }

    }
```

However, after joining the server, where this code is running, to the domain the decryption suddenly stopped working. I have debugged this so far that I found that the problem seems to be with

```
RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding)
```

that gives an exception

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The parameter is incorrect.
>
> at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
>
> at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle pKeyContext, Byte[] pbEncryptedKey, Int32 cbEncryptedKey, Boolean fOAEP, ObjectHandleOnStack ohRetDecryptedKey)
>
> at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] rgb, Boolean fOAEP)
>
> at MyCalculation.ProjectBase.RSADecrypt(Byte[] DataToDecrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, Boolean DoOAEPPadding)

How to proceed with this and where to look for possible reason for this? Note: This code was working before the server was joined to domain.

Edit:
Alex K. asked if the key container I'm using is empty. That is what I also suspected. However, at least the Modulus field of my public key had some data. I'm not able to run debugger in the production environment, but I wrote some code that writes byte arrays into a log file.

```
RSAParameters PublicKey = GetKeyFromContainer("CorroredKeys");
WriteLog("PublicKey, modulus: " + BytesToString(PublicKey.Modulus));
```

Just for information, the public key is generated like this:

```
    public static RSAParameters GenKey_SaveInContainer(string ContainerName)
    {

        // First, to get a fresh key, delete the key from the container.
        DeleteKeyFromContainer(ContainerName);

        // Create the CspParameters object and set the key container 
        // name used to store the RSA key pair.
        CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
        cp.KeyContainerName = ContainerName;


        // Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider that accesses
        // the key container MyKeyContainerName and generates new public and private key data
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp))
        {
            byte[] Keyblob = RSA.ExportCspBlob(true);
            // Return saved key information to the caller
            return RSA.ExportParameters(false);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Clears and deletes an asymmetric key pair from given key container
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ContainerName">Key container name where RSA key pair is saved</param>
    public static void DeleteKeyFromContainer(string ContainerName)
    {
        // Create the CspParameters object and set the key container 
        // name used to store the RSA key pair.
        CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
        cp.KeyContainerName = ContainerName;

        // Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider that accesses
        // the key container.
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);

        // Delete the key entry in the container.
        rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;

        // Call Clear to release resources and delete the key from the container.
        rsa.Clear();

    }
```

The key is read from container like this:

```
public static RSAParameters GetKeyFromContainer(string ContainerName)
{
    // Create the CspParameters object and set the key container 
    // name used to store the RSA key pair.
    CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
    cp.KeyContainerName = ContainerName;

    // Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider that accesses
    // the key container MyKeyContainerName.

    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp))
    {
        // Return saved key information to the caller
        return RSA.ExportParameters(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using user level key containers and logon as a domain user then you will have a different profile and hence a different (empty) key container, is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that after joining the server to the domain the two processes that encode and decode the data were running on two different user ids. When this was corrected and data first encoded again the encoded data could be decoded again.

This was so silly case, that I should have discovered this immediately. Lesson learned: Never trust that settings remain as they were.